# Excel VBA advanced filter to exclude data

Tags: excel, vba, advanced-filter

I'm filtering data in a table based on customer reference numbers. Is there a VBA code I could use to filter out rows based on their customer reference number?

I'm using a very handy code I found online that includes data based on customer reference number that looks like this:

```
Dim rgData As Range, rgCriteria As Range, rgOutput As Range

Set rgData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Set rgCriteria = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("I1").CurrentRegion
Set rgOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("A1")

rgData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rgCriteria, rgOutput
```

The code works by including only the customers found in the table that starts in cell "I1" in sheet 1, it then goes to the table that starts in celle "A1" and only includes customers that have the customer reference numbers and then sends the table to sheet 2.

Is there a way that I could change the above code so that it excludes those customer reference numbers found in the table in cell "I1"?

Thanks,

Comment: No. You'd need to use a different criteria range with the appropriate formula in it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you know how I can do that in with VBA?

Comment: Not without knowing more about the data layout. Is it just one column?

Comment: Yes - the table that includes all the customer reference numbers is just one column. The table that I want to filter has 7 columns and a varying amount of rows - depending on the table I want to sort.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub advanced_filter()

    Dim rgData As Range, rgCriteria As Range, rgOutput As Range
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1")
        Set rgData = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set rgCriteria = .Range("D1").CurrentRegion
        Set rgOutput = .Range("F1")
    
        .Range("F1:G7").ClearContents
        rgData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rgCriteria, rgOutput

        Set rgData = .Range("A8").CurrentRegion
        Set rgCriteria = .Range("D8").CurrentRegion
        Set rgOutput = .Range("F8")
    
        .Range("F8:G15").ClearContents
        rgData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rgCriteria, rgOutput
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but for some reason I get an execution error "1004: This can't be applied to the selected range. Select a single cell in a range and try again.Select a single cell in a range and try again."  I get this error on the following line of code 'rgData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rgCriteria, rgOutput'

Comment: Here it's working without problems! Add the following prior to the "rgdata.advancedfilter ..." line:  

`rgData.Select : MsgBox "rgdata:" & rgData.Address  
        
        rgCriteria.Select : MsgBox "rgCriteria:" & rgCriteria.Address  
        
        rgOutput.Select : MsgBox "rgOutput:" & rgOutput.Address`